# Is it possible to determine usb protocol from an installed driver?

Tags: usb, arduino, webcam, drivers

Just as the question states, the goal is to reverse engineer the protocol used by a device.

Let's say you have a webcam, an Arduino and an Arduino USB Host shield. You want to talk to that webcam, from which you don't know the protocol. Can it be done by monitoring USB data packets and by analyzing the driver installed for that device?

It would be a really interesting project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I often use a serial spy program to look at the conversation between two devices. In windows you can pay for it...
http://www.sinnovations.com/htdocs/serial-port-monitor.htm
In Linux it's free...
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-monitor-data-on-a-serial-port-in-linux/

Comment: Were you able to successfully determine the protocols using this serial monitor alone?

Comment: Well, when you say "protocol", I know that my devices are using RS-232. I am able to determine the questions and answers the two devices are passing back and forth to one another. If the device exchange occurs using any ASCII protocol (e.g., modbus) you should be able to see it IMO. It's free on Linux so I would advise trying it out.